# Deletion problem in teamsite/datadeploy

Tags: database, content-management-system, teamsite

I have a DCT that is being used to populate a database using DataDeploy to send the content from the DCR to the database. Everything works fine when I create or update the DCRs, but when I try to delete a DCR, DataDeploy doesn't delete the record in the database.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set an attribute in your DD definition. Check the docs. It is named like 'doDeletes'